# Exclude global holidays from selected dates

Tags: python, odoo

here how can I exclude countries holiday from selected date. here I added holidays.BD(years=[2022, 2023, 2024, 2025]).items(): for my countries holiday now I want to exclude these date from my selected date please help. I want to count total hour per day 8 hour working day and exclude my countries holiday. I exclude weekly 2 days holiday. now I want to exclude my countries holiday.

````
    def _compute_hours(self):
        for date in holidays.BD(years=[2022, 2023, 2024, 2025]).items():
            print(str(date[0]))
        if self.start_date and self.date_deadline:
            t1 = datetime.strptime(str(self.start_date), '%Y-%m-%d')
            print(t1)
            t2 = datetime.strptime(str(self.date_deadline), '%Y-%m-%d')
            print('=================================T2')
            print(t2)
            t3 = t2 - t1
            delta = timedelta(days=1)
            count = 0
            while t1 <= t2:
                print(t1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                t1 += delta
                if t1.weekday() in [5, 6] and date.days():
                    print('holiday')
                    count += 1
            print("total holidays", count)
            # count = sum(1 for day in t3 if day.weekday() < 5)
            # print(count)
            print('=================================T3')
            print(t3)
            print('=================================')
            seconds = t3.total_seconds() / 3
            diff_in_hours = seconds / 3600
            print('Difference between two datetimes in hours:')
            # print(diff_in_hours)
            self.total_hours = diff_in_hours - (count * 8)```
````

Comment: There is global leaves option in Odoo `Settings -> Technical -> Resource -> Working Times`. It may help you.

Comment: I have already define my country holiday but I do not understand how can I exclude the holidays